# gvnix over Jboss 6 and Oracle

Tags: oracle, jboss, gvnix

I have installed gvnix geo-petclinic example over Tomcat and Postgis without problems. Next I tried to install it over Jboss and Oracle

I changed roo script with:

```
jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database ORACLE --userName user --databaseName dbname --password pass --hostName host
```

When I tried to run it, I get this error:

```
13:24:57,781 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."geo-gvnix-jboss-oracle2.war#persistenceUnit": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."geo-gvnix-jboss-oracle2.war#persistenceUnit": java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Can't find a delegate
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:103) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744) [rt.jar:1.7.0_45]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.1.1.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.1.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Can't find a delegate
    at net.bull.javamelody.JpaPersistence.guessDelegate(JpaPersistence.java:202)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JpaPersistence.loadOrGuessDelegate(JpaPersistence.java:170)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JpaPersistence.findDelegate(JpaPersistence.java:162)
    at net.bull.javamelody.JpaPersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(JpaPersistence.java:124)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:200) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.access$600(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:57) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:99) [jboss-as-jpa-7.3.0.Final-redhat-14.jar:7.3.0.Final-redhat-14]
    ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Can't find a delegate
    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

gvNIX generates Java standard applications, so you should run your application on JBoss EAP 6.2+ server without problem... but you need to apply some little changes ;)...

- **Provided libraries**: JBoss provides persistence libraries unlike tomcat. You should set as *provided* persistence components on **pom.xml** *(remember set your oracle driver as provided if needed and add oracle driver to JBOSS Server)*

  `<dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
     <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
     <version>4.2.2.Final</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
     <exclusions>
       <exclusion>
          <groupId>cglib</groupId>
          <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
       <exclusion>
         <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
       </exclusion>
     </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
     <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
     <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
     <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
     <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>`
- **Path conflicts**: JBoss doesn't like '*' on *classpath* configuration, so you need to modify **web.xml** file with:

  `<context-param>
     <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
     <param-value>classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml,classpath:META-INF/
  spring/applicationContext-security.xml
    </param-value>
  </context-param>`
- **DataSource**: gvNIX applications running on JBoss EAP 6.2.0+ needs to configure a valid JNDI Datasource for data access. So you need to modify your  Datasource configuration on **applicationContext.xml** file as the following:

  1. Comment current BasicDatasource
  2. Add the following JNDI Datasource configuration:

     `<tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
     <tx:jta-transaction-manager />
     <jee:jndi-lookup id="entityManagerFactory" jndi-name="java:jboss/medaleaEntityManagerFactory"
     expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory" />`
  3. Modify **transaction-type** to **JTA** on **persistence.xml**. Your **persistence.xml** file will be as follow:

     `[...]
     <persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
      <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
      <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/YOURDATASOURCENAME</jta-data-source>
      <properties>
        [...]
        <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name"
     value="java:jboss/medaleaEntityManagerFactory"/>
      </properties>
     </persistence-unit>
     </persistence>`

With changes above, your project should run on JBoss EAP 6.2+ server ;)

Comment: Hi @jcgarcia I´ve done the changes that you suggested me but I get other error. I´m testing with other version of Hibernate Spatial. Do you know what could be the problem?. Thnks

Comment: I have read all documents about gvNix but it always uses Tomcat. Can I find an example to Jboss @jcgarcia ?. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The Java EE spec says:

> EE.8.2.3
>
> Library Conflicts If an application includes a bundled
>   version of a library, and the same library exists as an installed
>   library, the instance of the library bundled with the application
>   should be used in preference to any installed version of the library.
>   This allows an application to bundle exactly the version of a library
>   it requires without being influenced by any installed libraries. Note
>   that if the library is also a required component of the Java EE
>   platform version on which the application is being deployed, the
>   platform version may (and typically will) take precedence.

gvNIX generates apps that include bundled libraries, so jcgarcia showed the way to customize a generated app to remove the persistence module (because its a required component) from it and configure the app to get the persistence resources from JBoss.

You only have to install H-Spatial as JBoss module in order to be provided by JBoss.